# How to format fields read from pdf with iText java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flatten

I want to read every editable field from a pdf file, and given their origin format, save the flattened pdf

This is what I tried to do to save the flattened pdf with every field

```
    FileInputStream existingFileStream = new FileInputStream (src);

    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader (existingFileStream);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper (pdfReader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    HashMap map = (HashMap) form.getFields();
    Set s = map.keySet();
    int i = 0;
    for (Iterator it = s.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
         String key = (String) it.next();
         i++;
         //Grabamos en el campo el valor de un contador

         form.setField(key,form.getField(key));
    }

    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(true);
    stamper.close ();
    pdfReader.close ();
```

With this code I've achieved to flatten the pdf but I dont know how to format all the fields.

An example of the problem is that if the origin PDF has 2 empty editable fields, the result PDF does not save the value of those fields.

Comment: Explain "format the fields". Explain "does not save the value of those fields". Improve your question if you expect an answer. I don't think anyone understands what you're asking.

Comment: *if the origin PDF has 2 empty editable fields, the result PDF does not save the value of those fields.* - Which value of an **empty** field do you expect to be saved?

Comment: Hello @mkl, If the origin PDF has 2 empty editable fields, i expect to save 2 empty fields. I want to generate a flattened copy of the original PDF, with a redeable format in all cases.

Comment: Hello @Bruno Lowagie, When I said format fields I was referring that regardless of the input value the result of the out was legible. For example ,I have had problems as mentioned above: if the input text color of a field is blank on the output does not appear, or depending on the font field in the input, on the output is larger than its frame etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of what you write makes sense. Ask a colleague to improve your question.

Comment: @Cristian *i expect to save 2 empty fields* - but they are there. Look, emptiness at both locations! Seriously, please share sample file to explain what you are after.